# Date String manipulation in Excel VBA

Tags: excel, vba, datetime

The VBA built-in `Date` variable can give me today's date (`8/25/21` as the time this post is written). However, I really want the date in the `mm/dd/yyyy` format for future projects and store it in a variable - `myDate`. I just couldn't think of an easy string manipulation solution to get the desired result.

I've tried put the `Date` variable in excel sheets and then change the number format using the below code:

```
[A1]=Date
[A1].NumberFormat="mm/dd/yyyy"
myDate=[A1].value
debug.print myDate
```

Even though the number format code will change the appearance of cell [A1], making it look like it's in the desired format `mm/dd/yyyy`, the `debug.print` line still gives `8/25/21` instead of `08/25/2021`

Comment: Number format doesn't change the underlying value. `myDate = Format$(Date, "mm/dd/yyyy")`

Comment: you are right. Can you please explain what does the "$" sign do?

Comment: `Format$` returns a String. `Format` returns a Variant/String. Either works here

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A date value holds no format. Apply the format for display - that includes when calling `Debug.Print`:

```vb
Dim myValue As Date

[A1] = Date
[A1].NumberFormat = "mm/dd/yyyy"
myDate = [A1].Value
Debug.Print Format(myDate, "mm/dd/yyyy")
```